# How to get list of files with specified extensions and excluding few directories?

Tags: java, fileutils, apache-commons-io

I need to list files(specified extensions) from a directory excluding a few subdirectories.

I'm able to filter with extensions but not with two conditions
1) Files should be filtered by extension
2) Should exclude few subdirectories

```
    File dir = new File("D:\\SomeDir");
    String[] extensions = new String[] { "txt", "java" };
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    }
```

How to exclude selected subdirectories?

Comment: What about using [`listFilesAndDirs`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFilesAndDirs(java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFile)Filter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this code:**

```
// for exlude file extension  
NotFileFilter suffixFileFilterFileFilter=new NotFileFilter(new 
SuffixFileFilter(new String[] { "txt", "java" }));  

//to include only selected extension use below one
//IOFileFilter suffixFileFilterFileFilter= new SuffixFileFilter(new String[] { "java", "txt" });

NotFileFilter directoryFileFilterFileFilter=new NotFileFilter(new 
PrefixFileFilter(new String[] { "tolearn", "dir2" }));   // for directory
File dir = new File("D:\\SomeDir");
List<File> fileList  = (List<File>)  FileUtils.listFiles(dir,suffixFileFilterFileFilter,directoryFileFilterFileFilter);
    for (File file : fileList) {
        System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    }
```

Comment: This code is excluding **txt** and **java** extension. How to include only selected extensions.

Comment: @MahipalReddy use this `IOFileFilter suffixFileFilterFileFilter= new SuffixFileFilter(new String[] { "java", "txt" });`

Comment: @MahipalReddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\cosmap\\Documents\\travel-expenses");
    List<String> excludedDirs = Arrays.asList("src", ".git");
    List<String> extensions = Arrays.asList("xml", "yml");

    listFiles(dir, excludedDirs, extensions).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<File> listFiles(File currentFile, List<String> excludedDirs, List<String> extensions) {
    List<File> out = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = currentFile.listFiles();

    // might be null
    if(files == null) {
        return out;
    }

    for (File file : files) {
        // add recursively only if is directory and not in the excluded list
        if(file.isDirectory() && !excludedDirs.contains(file.getName())) {
            out.addAll(listFiles(file, excludedDirs, extensions));
        // add if is file and in the allowed extensions list
        } else if (file.isFile() && extensions.contains(file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1))) {
            out.add(file);
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: This seems good. Replaced ```if(file.isDirectory() && !excludedDirs.contains(file.getName()))``` with ```if(file.isDirectory() && !excludedDirs.contains(file.getAbsolutePath())) ```. Passing complete path in excludeDirs list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs` or, another solution:
instead of list all dirs and exclude a few directories you can exclude subdirectories in line 3 `List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, *false*);` and include in a second loop your subdirecories you want to list the files.